# Fetching tokens present in javascript file

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some client side javascript code that we expect to be reverse engineered at some point. I want a way that we can say with a reasonable degree of certainty that we are not exposing any debug information. We are running the code through uglify, so it obfuscates the variable names.

My thought was to fetch all the string literals (and tokens?) from the file and match them using a jest snapshot, but I can't find a tool that will pull the information from the JS file. Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Update:
I think it would help if I gave an example

Suppose someone were to write this code:

```
function processSensitiveData () {
  console.log('processing sensitive data')
  doMoreThings();
}

processSensitiveData();
```

There is nothing wrong with that because we strip console.log statements in production, and uglify transforms the function name, so no sensitive information is present. Suppose someone were to modify it to this code:

```
function processData (dataType) {
  console.log('processing ' + dataType + ' data');
  doMoreThings();
}

processData('sensitive');
```

Now, while the console.log statement gets stripped out, 'sensitive' will still be in the final output. It's this kind of thing that we want to avoid. While code reviews are the first line of defense, this is very likely to be missed in a code review, especially if combined with other changes. I'd like to have the computer do it, as that is something that a computer would do much better than a human. Ideally, it would be a linting rule, but that would be a very complicated rule to write.

Comment: You ***cannot*** hide information on the client side

Comment: It's not about hiding the information, it's about making sure it's not present in the first place (in production). It's more just to make sure that someone didn't make an oops and leave in something that is not necessary and may be a clue to a potential attacker.

Comment: The same can happen when you get the information from a server... You have to find other ways of making sure that no code that shouldn't be public, is public

Answer (score 0):

Code reviews.  This way if you review any and all code checked into source you will be aware if there is debugging information that is trying to sneak its way into your repo.  Besides that you can keyword search before deployment as well for 'alert', 'debug'  and other debugging JavaScript keywords.